# The username in my terminal bash is not my name. How to fix it? Do I have security concern?

Tags: bash, mac, terminal

I ran a sklearn update last week, and today when I opened my terminal, the user name is not mine anymore (as shown in the screenshot, I have no idea who is Yakov).

[image: screenshot of terminal window and prompt]

Anybody has any idea why this happened and how to get my username back?

Comment: I think this is off-topic here, rather ask on apple.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Formal notes: The comment above was migrated from Server Fault along with the question and "here" in it still refers to Server Fault. For the record: the question is on-topic here on Super User. I guess it would be on-topic on apple.stackexchange.com as well (but if you decide to post there then please [keep at most one copy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64073/355310)).